# Sphinx return zero value using php even if data is available for String value

Tags: php, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have been facing issue with sphinx result set for string attribute. Below is my sphinx result set which is returning zero for the string attributes (title and others)

```
[matches] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 83597
                    [weight] => 1
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (

                [title] => 0
                [others] => 0
                [zoneid] => 19
                [phoneverified] => 0
                [vcardenabled] => 0

             )

                )

        )

    [total] => 1
    [total_found] => 1
    [time] => 0.000
```

In the above sphinx result, the "others" and "title" fields are String but it is returning with 0 even if value is available in sphinx

Below is the my expected result.

```
[matches] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 83597
                    [weight] => 1
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (

                [title] => 
                [others] => yadheen
                [zoneid] => 19
                [phoneverified] => 0
                [vcardenabled] => 0

             )

                )

        )

    [total] => 1
    [total_found] => 1
    [time] => 0.000
```

**Please suggest on this!**

FYR: I am using sphinx 2.0.4

Comment: why have you tagged this 'thinking-sphinx'? From your print_r and the php5 - appears you actully using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using an old version of sphinxapi code.

make sure you are using the latest version - use the one from the sphinx distribution you downloaded. (in the api/ folder)

Comment: Concerning api, compiled PHP module seems to be outdated, so plain PHP version should be used.

Comment: the plain php version generally performs better than the module anyway! absolutly no reason to use the module.